# JQuery to swap elements

Tags: jquery

My PHP script creates a table with several rows of items. Column1 in each row displays emptybox.jpg, and the last column is an anchor link to select the item on that row:

```
output .= '<a href="./select_item.php id=select'.$product['id'].'"></a>';
output .= '<a href="./deselect_item.php id=deselect'.$product['id'].' style.display='"none"'"></a>';
```

(Note that the style is included inline just for this post -- all styles reside in an external css, and I use a class= to hide all deselect anchors by default)

When an anchor is clicked (item is selected) I want jquery to swap emptybox.jpg for checkmark.jpg, and to swap the "Select" anchor for the  anchor. Ideally, those should be toggles, so the reverse would also work (clicking DeSelect will hide both checkmark.jpg and the DeSelect anchor, and will redisplay both emptybox.jpg and the Select anchor).

Each row icon is identified by a  tag, with the productID number appended.

```
output .='<div class="checked" id="chk'.$product['id'].'"><img="checkmark.jpg" /></div>';
output .='<div class="empty" id="mt'.$product['id'].'" .style.display="none"><img="emptybox.jpg" /></div>';
```

The jquery code must identify which "select" anchor tag was clicked so that it can show/hide the appropriate element pairs (emptybox.jpg/checkmark.jpg, and Select/Deselect anchors). Here's what I have so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$("a").click(function(){
    $("#mt").hide();
    $("#chk").show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you post the actual HTML of a couple of rows?  Without seeing the HTML structure it is hard to give you useful jQuery.

Edit:  OK.  Use the power of CSS to simplify the task. I usually do something like this:

Add these CSS Styles:

```
tr td.artchek div.empty, tr td.arthref div.a_sel
{ display: block; }
tr.selected td.artchek div.empty, tr.selected td.arthref div.a_sel
{ display: none; }
tr td.artchek div.checked, tr td.arthref div.a_desel
{ display: none; }
tr.selected td.artchek div.checked, tr.selected td.arthref div.a_desel
{ display: block; }
```

And this jQuery:

```
$('td.artchek a').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass('selected');
});
```

Comment: Editing the original post would make it too long, so I posted the function that gens the HTML here (drag down the horiz view separator so you can see the full function): http://jsfiddle.net/a7fxj/

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
<div class=line>
    <a href="./select_item.php" class="select"></a>
    <div class="empty"><img src="emptybox.jpg" /></div>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
$(".line").click(function(){
    var link = $(this).find("a");
    var checkbox = $(this).find("div");

    link.toggleClass("select");
    link.toggleClass("deselect");
    if(link.hasClass("select")) { link.attr("href","./select_item.php"); }
    else { link.attr("href","./deselect_item.php"); }

    checkbox.toggleClass("empty");
    checkbox.toggleClass("checked");
    if(checkbox.hasClass("empty")) { checkbox.find("img").attr("src","emptybox.jpg"); }
    else { checkbox.find("img").attr("src","checkmark.jpg"); }
}
```

This toggles both classes and properties. The variables aren't strictly necessary, but it certainly makes the code easier to both read and write.